# Add 1.6.0 Cordova plugin to 2.2.0 Cordova project

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How do I add a cordova plugin made on 1.6.0 to a 2.2.0 cordova project for iOS?

Upgrade the 1.6.0 project to 1.7.0, then 1.8.0 and so on (doesn't feel right)?

Or how do I resolve the current callback signature on the new Cordova(2.2.0) that uses "(CDInvokedURL *)command" as  parameter instead of (NSDictionary *)options?

More specifically, I am trying to add the Calendar Plugin for iOS to a Cordova 2.2.0 project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I added the plugin to a Cordova 2.0.0rc1 project. And it worked. From there, I upgraded to 2.1.0 and then to 2.2.0.

The trick was to make it work in 2.0.0. I had to figure out how to create my javascript and index.html files and how to make the call to my Obj-C native function since I am new to PhoneGap. And `(NSMutableArray *)arguments (NSMutableDictionary *)options` (which seemingly is deprecated according to Cordova documentation) still works on the later versions (i.e., 2.1.0 and 2.2.0) smoothly on the upgrade (I guess until it gets deprecated completely, it will work).

**EDIT**:

The other big question which currently has no answer is [this one](https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect/issues/221), in the latest Cordova versions, possibly from 2.0.0 (correct me if i am wrong)

This is the signature of the function that needs to be implemented ->

`- (void)echo:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command`

and this is the offending code ->

`[self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];`

I found the property `callbackId` in the class `CDVInvokedURLCommand`. I have no clue what it is complaining about.